# Rails website with user local storage instead of central database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a Ruby on Rails website for a state University Agricultural Research facility, and the website will run on a University server.  Because of this, the data on the server will be accessible via the state Public Records Act (the state version of the Freedom of Information Act).   Some of the users of the system will be commercial growers who do not want their business data available via public records.

Given the situation described above, I would like to have the user's data NOT be stored on the server, but rather be something that the user can load/save from their own local machine.   In other words, they should be able to use the website as a guest, and populate the data model from their own machine, but not have that data be persisted on the server.   (Other data which is not business-sensitive will be stored in the database).

My question is:   has anybody else had any experience developing a system like this, and are there any gems out there that back-end ActiveRecord to a non-database, and that can be loaded/saved from local storage?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: maybe store the data within a per user cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to have write access the user's hard drive directly through your app, so any local storage method you use will not be truly persistent with changes (unless your users are savvy enough to upload a file, make changes, and then download a new file and keep it all straight (which with 99.999% certainty they won't be)).

That said, you can use local storage with various degrees of persistence, depending on the user's habits.  You have a couple of options:

**1. Cookies**

With rails, you have easy access to write and read cookies like so

```
session[:data_name] = <your data>
session[:data_name] # => <your data>
```

However, this is limited to only 4kB and obviously will be cleared when the user clears their cookies.  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions for more.

**2. Web storage**

There is also a new-ish web standard coming together for larger local storage options, but again this is not guaranteed between sessions and is still browser-specific: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage

**3. Other options**

My suggestion would be to provide some sort of alternate database that the user could 'own', and host that on S3 or equivalent.  It could be a single database chopped up for all the users, or a separate database for each user, depending on your needs.

The more traditional solution here would be to build an actual app for the client to install on their machine that could access your service and have access to their hard drive.  But that just feels so 2010 ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tyler.   This was helpful.  As for the traditional app, that is what we are replacing.  It carried it's own set of problems.  :-)